# How to do a nested groupBy in Scala

Tags: json, scala, collections, group-by, nested

I have a list of case objects like this:

```
AppInfo(client = "client1", project = "project1", version = "version1")
AppInfo(client = "client1", project = "project1", version = "version2")
AppInfo(client = "client2", project = "project3", version = "version1")
AppInfo(client = "client2", project = "project4", version = "version1")
```

And need to make a nested structure like this:

```
Map(
  "clients" -> List(
    Map(
      "name" -> "client1",
      "projects" -> List(
        Map(
          "name" -> "project1",
          "versions" -> List(
            "version1",
            "version2"
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    Map(
      "name" -> "client2",
      "projects" -> List(
        Map(
          "name" -> "project3",
          "versions" -> List(
            "version1"
          )
        ),
        Map(
          "name" -> "project4",
          "versions" -> List(
            "version1"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

That looks awful, but it will serialize to this pretty-straightforward JSON:

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "name": "client1",
      "projects": [
        {
          "name": "project1",
          "versions": [
            "version1",
            "version2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "client2",
      "projects": [
        {
          "name": "project3",
          "versions": [
            "version1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "project4",
          "versions": [
            "version1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any reasonable way to do this? Right now I have maps within Maps within groupBys within Lists.

**EDIT**

Something like the [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) library for Clojure might help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for {
    (clientName, clientInfos) <- infoList.groupBy(_.client)
} yield {
    val clientProjects = clientInfos.groupBy(_.project)
    val projectSection = clientProjects.map { case(name, infos) => Map("name" -> name, "versions" -> infos.map(_.version)) }

    Map("name" -> clientName, "projects" -> projectSection)
}
```

It doesn't reduce the number of `map` or `groupBy` invocations, but that's the most convenient way I was able to organize the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! I like how you use pattern matching to avoid having to do stuff like  `tuple._1` and `tuple._2`.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of `AppInfo` case objects called `appInfos`, do `byClient(appInfos)`:

```
def byVersion(appInfos: List[AppInfo]) = appInfos
                                          .map(_.version)

def byProject(appInfos: List[AppInfo]) = appInfos
                                          .groupBy(_.project)
                                          .map(tuple => Map("name" -> tuple._1, "versions" -> byVersion(tuple._2)))

def byClient(appInfos: List[AppInfo]) = appInfos
                                          .groupBy(_.client)
                                          .map(tuple => Map("name" -> tuple._1, "projects" -> byProject(tuple._2)))
```

It's repetitive, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Case classes will give you better type safety than maps, but more ugliness:

Given a list of `AppInfo` case objects called `appInfos` do `byClient2(appInfos)`:

```
case class ProjectApps(name: String, versions: List[String])

object ProjectApps{
  def apply(tuple: (String, List[AppInfo])): ProjectApps =
                ProjectApps(name=tuple._1, versions=tuple._2.map(_.version))
}


case class ClientApps(name: String, projects: List[ProjectApps])

object ClientApps {
  def apply(tuple: (String, List[AppInfo])): ClientApps = {
    val name = tuple._1
    val projects = tuple._2.groupBy(_.project).map(ProjectApps.apply).toList
    ClientApps(name, projects)
  }
}


def byClient2(appInfos: List[AppInfo]): List[ClientApps] = 
                     appInfos.groupBy(_.client).map(ClientApps.apply).toList
```

Comment: Marked as the answer, because the type safety is good, and using case classes makes it easier to generate stuff like JSON schema or Swagger docs. It is **UGLY** though.